# Create different restrictions with a single rule_2

Tags: python, pyomo

This post is the continuation of the post "Create different restrictions with a single rule"

In this case I show my all code, trying to use the @AirSquid response to create my constraint called

```
model.node_limit
```

---

```
from pyomo.environ import*



model = ConcreteModel (name='WFLP')



import mydataWFLP


model.SP = Var(mydataWFLP.N, within=NonNegativeReals)

def obj_rule(model):
    return sum(mydataWFLP.h[n]*model.SP[n] for n in mydataWFLP.N)

model.obj = Objective(rule=obj_rule)



def SP_upper_bound_rule (model,n):
    return model.SP[n] <= mydataWFLP.P[n]

model.SP_upper_bound = Constraint(mydataWFLP.N, rule=SP_upper_bound_rule)

     
model.Nodo = Set(initialize = mydataWFLP.Nodo.keys())     

model.C = Set(model.Nodo, initialize=mydataWFLP.Nodo)           

def node_limit_rule (model,nodo):  
        
        return sum(model.SP[nodo] for other  in model.C[nodo]) <= sum(mydataWFLP.P[nodo] for other  in model.C)

model.node_limit = Constraint(model.Nodo, rule=node_limit_rule)




opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
results = opt.solve(model)
model.display()
model.obj.pprint()
model.SP_upper_bound.pprint()
model.node_limit.pprint()
```

The dataset used is

```
N = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 

M = [1,2,3] 



h = {1:400,2:300,3:200,4:100,5:50,6:150,7:250} 



P = {1:20,2:12,3:18,4:27,5:30,6:39,7:34}

Nodo = {1: [1,2,3,4], \
     2: [3,4,5], \
     3: [5,6,7],}
```

I'm doing something wrong, because, now my constraint is the following

```
node_limit : Size=3, Index=Nodo, Active=True
    Key : Lower : Body                          : Upper : Active
      1 :  -Inf : SP[1] + SP[1] + SP[1] + SP[1] :  77.0 :   True
      2 :  -Inf :         SP[2] + SP[2] + SP[2] :  75.0 :   True
      3 :  -Inf :         SP[3] + SP[3] + SP[3] :  103.0 :   True
```

Now, it does create the constraints with the number of variables I have defined, but it does not create the constraints with the variables I want, that are

```
node_limit : Size=3, Index=Nodo, Active=True
    Key : Lower : Body                          : Upper : Active
      1 :  -Inf : SP[1] + SP[2] + SP[3] + SP[4] :  60.0 :   True
      2 :  -Inf :         SP[3] + SP[4] + SP[5] :  36.0 :   True
      3 :  -Inf :         SP[5] + SP[6] + SP[7] :  54.0 :   True
```

How can I fix it?

The fist post is here

[Create different restrictions with a single rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75285239/create-different-restrictions-with-a-single-rule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  You just have an error within both of your `sum()` statements.  This is yours:

```
def node_limit_rule (model,nodo):          
        return sum(model.SP[nodo] for other  in model.C[nodo]) <= sum(mydataWFLP.P[nodo] for other  in model.C)
```

In both sums you are summing *copies* of the same thing because you are summing (in the first part) `SP[nodo]` multiple times.  You can see the repetition in the output that you posted above.  You want to some over `other` like so:

```
def node_limit_rule (model,nodo):  
        return sum(model.SP[other] for other  in model.C[nodo]) <= sum(mydataWFLP.P[other] for other  in model.C)
```

You are using `nodo` to look into `model.C` to get the set of the `others` and then you want to sum over all of the **`others`**... make sense?

A couple other nit-picks...

In the future, you'll get better response on this site if you make a tiny reproducible example that others can just copy and tinker with.  Yours is close, but you could just put your data into your example with a little extra work so that it "just runs"

I don't see where you are printing/inspecting the results of your optimization.  This **will bite you**.  You need to ensure that the termination condition is what you expect.

Lastly, just a recommendation, you should organize your models a little better and comment them.  Much easier to share/collaborate.  Put the sets together, say what they mean, etc.  See my other posts on this site with [pyomo] tag for examples.

Comment: @AirSquidThank you very much for your explanation and advice. I will take them into account in the future